# Great grandmother's gravestone

Tags: vocabulary

[image: Elisabeth Steckel Tombstone**strong text**]
Any help deciphering the words would be appreciated.  Here is my attempt:

Hier ruhet der
leib 
von elizabeth steckel 
Eine geboren Suse sie ward
Geboren den 29 Junius 1807 
Gestorben den 28 Junius 1827 
All gewerden gefahr weniger 
erd ist 
Sie warefte Ehe een yon
Carl Steckel leig ein sind

Gott sind ?  ?  ?  ?
 Nicht  ?  ?  ?  ?  Gott ?
Nicht ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  deiner

Comment: That's really hard. I considered the framed part to start with "Gott Segne..." ("God bless...") and thought that it might be a common bible verse or so, but no luck with google here. Is this scanned from an old photo? (That is: Is there any better image available? Even the JPG compression seems rather high...)

Comment: "Alt geworden 20 Jahr ..." würde ich sagen. "Die warigste Ehegattin von Cart Steckel ..."? Zwar hilft Deutsch beim Erraten fehlender Buchstaben und das Wissen, dass das altdeutsche s dem f ähnlich sieht, aber so recht passt die Frage nicht hier hin.

Comment: The tombstone is in the Old Salem Church cemetery at Moorestown just north of Bath, PA.  Yes, I knew I would get caught of the G-Grandmother thing she is actually my 3x great but once you are at great it becomes clumsy after that.

Comment: Yes this is the best photo I have.  It was taken years ago and the original stone has only deteriorated more as the elements have worn away softer parts of the stone.  I agree that the bottom box must be averse of some sort.

Comment: Thanks, we have made some progress.  I think these are the words on the top portion, except for the second to last word "leigieda"?Hier ruht der
leib 
von elizabeth steckel 
Eine geboren Susz sie ward  
Geboren den 29 Junius 1807 
Gestorben den 28 Junius 1827 
Alt geworden 20 Jahr weniger 
ein tag
sie war die Ehegattin von
Carl Steckel leigieda sind

Gott segne
 Nicht         Des Gott
Nicht deiner

Comment: @Karl Just to avoid any misunderstanding: you really don't even have _this_ photo in better (technical) quality? (E.g. higher resolution / more pixel) Can't believe that this is the original file - both scanners and digital cameras should produce larger files.

Comment: no this is the best i have.  sorry

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't fit the scope of the site. - In my opinion it would be a better fit on [genealogy.se], as transcription issues are a regular topic there. They have a tag "records" for this type of issue, specifically.

Answer (score 3):

This is the very best try of mine out of this poor picture:

> HIER RUHET DER
>   LEIB
>   von ELISABETH STECKEL
>   Eine geborne Surst(??) Sie Ward
>   Geboren den 29(?) Junius 1807
>   Gestorben den 28(?) Junius 1827
>   Alt geworden 20 Jahr Weniger
>   ein Tag
>   Sie War die Ehegattin von
>   Carl Steckel (?) Zeigte(?) das Kind(?)
>   Gott Segne…………………
>   Nie……… der Gott??
>   Nicht…………….dein…

"Surst" or whatever it says in the fourth line would probably have been her maiden name. I cannot understand what it says after the the name of her husband Carl. Maybe it could be something local as a name of a town or village in Pennsylvania? Maybe it is something in Pennsylvania Dutch?

Comment: Yes, I think her maiden name was Süsz and after looking at the word after Carl Steckel I think it says Zeigte?